# Solving for a single variable in a quadratic system

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations

I have a quadratic system of $n$ equations that looks like:
$$ A_{ij}x_{j}y + B_{ij}x_{j}=0 $$

For $i=0...n$, where $A_{i,j}$ and $B_{ij}$ are integer matrices and sums over $j$ are implied. Is there some efficient way to solve this system for y only, without having to implicitly solve all $x_{j}$?

(Bonus question: what if the system looks like $ A_{ijk}x_{j}y_{k} + B_{ij}x_{j}=0 $?)

Comment: So $y$ is a scalar? If $A$ is invertible, you can multiply through by $A^{-1}$. You then get something that should remind you of eigenvectors. If $A$ is not invertible, then there may be no solutions.

Comment: @lemon, j doesn't go from $0$ through $n$.

Comment: I see $n+1$ equations (one for each $i$, $0\le i\le n$) and only one unknown, $y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is a texbook example of "generalized eigenvalue problem". It is a standard problem implemented in numerical libraries such as lapack.

The routines that compute solutions of the eigenproblem may be used to yield only the eigenspectrum without computing eigenvectors that is $x.$ They are also quicker in that case.

This is a reference:
http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node35.html